# JavaScript picture slideslow not show

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

What's the problem here, everything worked well until 2 days ago!

JavaScript code:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    "use strict";
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("istaknutiOglasi");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 10000);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="single_sidebar wow fadeInDown">
<h2><span>Istaknuti Oglasi</span></h2>
<div class="sideAdd">
<img class="istaknutiOglasi" src="/images/Istaknuti_Oglasi.png">
<img class="istaknutiOglasi" src="/images/Banner_2.png">
</div>
</div>
```

On google shows me error to `x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qgxa98ru/ it is working i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things :

```
if (slideIndex > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
```

Should be changed to:

```
if (slideIndex >= x.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
    }
```

and

```
x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
```

should be changed to:

```
x[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
```

Here's a working example

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    "use strict";
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("istaknutiOglasi");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex >= x.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
    }
    x[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="single_sidebar wow fadeInDown">
<h2><span>Istaknuti Oglasi</span></h2>
<div class="sideAdd">
<img class="istaknutiOglasi" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300">
<img class="istaknutiOglasi" src="https://unsplash.it/200/400">
</div>
</div>
```

What was happening was that the indexes were trying to access elements outside of the array (x). This was a out of bounds error. How this helps you out!